# Visual Studio 13 ошибка при добавлении DataGridView

Tags: datagridview

При запуске программы появляется следующая ошибка. Первый раз она появилась когда попытался добавить на форму DataGridView.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибку надо также текстом приводить, а не только рисунком, чтобы потом другие могли найти этот вопрос по тексту ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно в процессе работы над проектом была изменена версия FrameWork.

Варианты решения:

- Изменить в проекте версию Framework на более позднюю (в которой есть поддержка свойства UpdateOrderOption)
- пересоздать DataSet (удалить и создать снова, если он используется)